# Unir cliente Linux a Active Directory y montar recursos mediante script de inicio de sesion

Tags: linux, debian, windows-server, activedirectory

Estamos en la empresa reciclando pc obsoletas para darle una segunda vida con linux, en la empresa tenemos un AD y cada grupo de usuarios o usuarios al iniciar su sesion en Windows Carga un script que hace un NET USE de unidades de red, deseo poder hacer lo mismo en linux, hasta ahora logre unirlas al dominio, pero el tema es que no logro generar un script para que ese usuario pueda montar recursos en red dependiendo de que usuario es?
Ejemplo carlos gomez que monte el recurso del file server SMB \FS01\Contable
y jose martinez que monte \FS01\administracion.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Probaste ingresando al recurso mediante ``smb://recurso/directorio/`` ?